# Using ArrayList to create a simple version of MS Paint

Tags: java, arraylist, stddraw

I have to create a simple version of MS Paint in java using StdDraw. Here are the requirements and my code:

In this class we'll write a simple MS Paint type program that lets you draw, and then save/load those drawings.  You'll implement 2 classes. A third class, Point2D.javaPreview the document, is provided for you.

Drawing
This class should contain an ArrayList of Point2D objects.  This class should also implement Serializable so that we can save/load our drawings.  It should include a constructor that sets the points to be an empty ArrayList.

It should also include method draw() that draws all the points.

It should include a method maybeAddPoint(Point2D p).  This should add the point unless it's the same as the last point in the ArrayList.  We don't want a bunch of copies of the same point when the user holds the mouse down for a while without moving it.

Finally, it should include a method clear() that clears the list of points and calls StdDraw.clear().

Driver
In main(), we'll create or load a Drawing object, draw it, and allow the user to edit it.

The program should try to load a Drawing object from the file "savedDrawing.dat" using the ObjectInputStream class.  If that fails for any reason, you should print that you were unable to open the file and create a new, blank Drawing object.  (Hint, code to create an empty drawing could go in a catch block).

Once you have a drawing object, create an animation loop.  In the loop you should check to see if the mouse is down (StdDraw.mousePressed() or StdDraw.isMousePressed()).  If it is, add a new point to your drawing (well, maybe.  Let your maybeAddPoint() method decide for you).  You should also accept 2 piece of keyboard input.  If the user hits the 'C' key, (hint, check with StdDraw.isKeyPressed()  You may need to use the keycode static constants in the KeyEvent class), clear the drawing.  If the user hits 'Q', break out of your loop.

When you exit your animation loop, use the ObjectOutputStream class to save your Drawing object to the the "savedDrawing.dat" file and print that it was saved.  If it fails for any reason, just print a message indicating the problem.  Once the file is saved (or it couldn't be saved for some reason), call System.exit() to end the program.

My Drawing class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw;

public class Drawing implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<Point2D> points;

    public Drawing() {
        points = new ArrayList<>(10);
    }

    public void draw(Point2D p) {
        for(int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {
            p = points.get(i);
            p.draw();
        }
    }
    public void maybeAddPoint(Point2D p) {
        if(p.equals(points.get(points.size()))) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        points.clear();
        StdDraw.clear();
    }
}
```

My Driver:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectInputStream in = null;
        Drawing point;
        Point2D draw;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("savedDrawing.dat"));
            point = (Drawing) in.readObject();
            while(true) {
                draw = new Point2D(StdDraw.mouseX(), StdDraw.mouseY());
                if(StdDraw.mousePressed()) {
                    point.maybeAddPoint(draw);
                    point.draw(draw);
                }
                if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('C')) {
                    point.clear();
                }
                if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('Q')) {
                    break;
                }
                in.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Unable to open the file.");
            point = new Drawing();
            while(true) {
                draw = new Point2D(StdDraw.mouseX(), StdDraw.mouseY());
                if(StdDraw.mousePressed()) {
                    point.maybeAddPoint(draw);
                }
                if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('C')) {
                    point.clear();
                }
                if(StdDraw.isKeyPressed('Q')) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        } 


    }

}
```

the Point2D class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw;

public class Point2D implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void draw() {
        StdDraw.point(x,y);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if(this.getClass() != other.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Point2D otherPoint = (Point2D)other;
        return this.x == otherPoint.x && this.y == otherPoint.y;
    }
}
```

I am getting an indexOutOfBoundsException in my maybeAddPoint method. It says the size of the ArrayList is 0. Is the equals method for the Point2D class being implemented wrong in this method?

Comment: tl;dr... If you don't know how to use the debugger, try to add `System.out.println(//someVariable//)` after the important issues in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You get an indexOutOfBoundsException because you are accessing to the index `points.size()`, but since the first index of an array in Java is 0, you have to get `points.size() - 1` to access the last element.

But you still have to check if the array is empty, otherwise you will get the same exception.